# Javascript promises catch block initiating when no error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

I have created a function that makes a call to an api shown below. I am displaying the message from setMessage on the front end. For some reason when there is no error the .catch block message flashes in setMessage() and then the setMessage() finally ends with the correct message from .then().

I'm not sure why this is.

```
function handleCoupon(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setMessage("");
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_API}/subscription/coupon/get`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        appliedCoupon: couponCode.toLowerCase().trim(),
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.coupon === true) {
          setMessage(data.message);
          setLoading(false);
        } else {
          setMessage(data.message);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      })
      .catch(
        (error) => console.log(error.message),
        setMessage("Something went wrong, please contact support")
      );
  }
```

Comment: are you doing this inside a `useEffect` hook? If so, are you setting a default value for `useEffect` so it doesn't run repeatedly?

Comment: That use of a comma operator is nasty. I'm personally not sure how that is parsed in an arrow function. Try changing it to `.catch((error) => { console.log(error); setMessage('....') })`.

Comment: ... properly format the statements into two lines of course. I only wrote the above to fit in the comment section

Comment: @RandyCasburn, no it is being called with a button onClick.

Comment: @slebetman are you saying that it may not be working correct because of the comma and that it should be a semi-colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **.catch** only accept **single** function as parameter, and you are passing 2 of them:

1. `(error) => console.log(error.message)`
2. `setMessage("Something went wrong, please contact support")`

Try merging them into 1 function, e.g.

```
.catch((error) => {
   console.log(error.message);
   setMessage("Something went wrong, please contact support");
});
```

Comment: Amazing, it worked! Thank you, appreciate your help!